# How to use binding pry with rspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm running into an issue with the following in my spec/controller/admin/locations_controller_spec.rb.

Specifically here:

```
describe 'create' do
it 'should create the record' do
  expect do
    binding.pry
    post :create, params: { location: FactoryBot.attributes_for(:location) }
  end.to change(Location, :count).by(1)
end
```

end

I'm guessing I put it in the correct location to hit it. What do I actually need to call on when using rails console to get output?

Comment: you need to install the required gems for the development environment, now you have them only on the test environment

Comment: I would have thought it (`binding.pry`) belonged in the actual controller code...

Comment: What command are you using to run your spec?

Comment: What happens when you run this spec?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the gem to your `test` group:

```
group :test do
  gem 'rspec'
  gem 'pry-byebug'
  gem 'pry-rails'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have required gems installed in test environment then you would see the binding when you run your rspec test

Answer (score 0):

Load pry and then type the followings:

require 'rspec/core'
require 'rspec/expectations'
include RSpec::Matchers